# setValue() in loop range

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have borrowed some script for a reminder e-mail to be sent. this works fine but after it sends i want it to set the value of a cell to state 'Yes' so that next time it loops it wont action that line.

i have tried a few things and did have it working at one point put it was setting the value on the wrong row. the line in question is the last line in the code below

```
function sendEmail() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Meeting Room Booking Requests');
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;   // Number of rows to process

  // Fetch the range of cells
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var range = dataRange.getValues();

    // get the spreadsheet object
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Meeting Room Booking Requests');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var startRow = 2;

  // grab column 17 (the 'difference' column)
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,17,lastRow-startRow+1,1);
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var time_left_values = range.getValues();

  // grab column 18 (the 'reminder sent' column)
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,18,lastRow-startRow+1,1);
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var remindersent = range.getValues();  

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  //Logger.log(data)

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var time_left = time_left_values[i][0];
    var reminder_sent = remindersent[i][0];

    if(reminder_sent == 'No')
      {
       if(time_left >= 0) 
          {
            var emailAddress = "test@test.co.uk";//row[6];  // First column
            var message = row[1];       // Second column
            var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
            MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
            sheet.getRange(data,17).setValue('Yes');   
    };    
  };
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

all sorted.....final code is below

```js
function sendEmail() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Meeting Room Booking Requests');
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;   // Number of rows to process

  var linkText = 'test@test.co.uk';

  // Fetch the range of cells
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  var range = dataRange.getValues();

    // get the spreadsheet object
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Meeting Room Booking Requests');
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var startRow = 2;

  // grab column 17 (the 'difference' column)
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,17,lastRow-startRow+1,1);
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var time_left_values = range.getValues();

  // grab column 18 (the 'reminder sent' column)
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,18,lastRow-startRow+1,1);
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var remindersent = range.getValues();

  // grab column 15 (the 'reminder time' column)
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,18,lastRow-startRow+1,1);
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var remindertime = range.getValues();    

  var emailaddressTo = ("test@test.co.uk");
  var emailaddressCC = ("test@test.co.uk, test@test.co.uk");
  var testemail = ("test@test.co.uk");

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  //Logger.log(data)

  for (i in data) 
  {
    var row = data[i];
    var time_left = time_left_values[i][0];
    var reminder_sent = remindersent[i][0];
    var reminder_time = remindertime[i][0];

      if(reminder_sent == 'No')
        {
         if(time_left >= 0) 
          {
            var emailAddress = "test@test.co.uk";//row[6];  // First column
            var room = row[0];       // First column
            var start = row[2];       // Third column
            var end = row[3];       // Fourth column
            var name = row[4];       // Fifth column
            var email = row[6];       // Seventh column
            var mailsubject = "Booking Reminder";

            var body = "Hi " + name + "," + "<br />" +
                       "<br />" + "You have the below room booked in the London office:"  + "<br />" +
                       "<br />" + "<b>Room:</b>" + " " + room + 
                       "<br />" + "<b>Required From:</b>" + " " + start + 
                       "<br />" + "<b>Required To:</b>" + " " + end + "<br />" + 
                       "<br />" + "If for any reason you do not require this room please contact: " + linkText.link(linkText); 

            MailApp.sendEmail(
                               {

                                to:       email,
                                //noReply:  true,  
                                replyTo:  testemail,//emailaddressCC,
                                cc:       testemail,//emailaddressCC,
                                subject:  mailsubject,
                                htmlBody: body,
                                name:     'oom Booking'
                                }
                              );
            data[i][17] = "Yes";  
          };    
        };
  };
  dataRange.setValues(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getValues() returns an Array with base 0, getRange() works with base 1, just sum 1 to the Range. Don't forget that when using for-in, the index in the Array is treated as a String.

Comment: mmm, i have got it setting the value now using - sheet.getRange(i+1,18).setValue('Yes'); - but with the current data i would expect it to populate it in row 2 and 5 in column 18. it is puttting them in column 18 but in rows 1 and 31??